# What are the criteria for allowing repeated bare NPs in coordinate structures?

Tags: noun-phrases, zero-article, coordinating-conjunctions

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Pages 409-410):

> **8.5 Restricted non-referential interpretations of bare NPs**
>
> [...] This time, however, our concern is with bare NPs. We confine our attention to singular count nouns, which normally require a determiner.
>
> **(a) Bare role NPs**
>
> ...
>
> **(b) Fixed expressions or frames**
>
> ...
>
> vi *`arm` in `arm`*, *`back` to `back`*, *`day` after `day`*, *`mouthful` by `mouthful`*, *`side` by `side`*, *`mile` upon `mile`* [repeated nouns]
>
> vii *from `father` to `son`*, *from `beginning` to `end`*, *between `husband` and `wife`*, *`mother` and `child`* [matched nouns]
>
> ...
>
> The examples in [vi–vii] are illustrative of a number of expressions involving repetition of the same noun or contrasting nouns; [...]. Similarly, **in coordinate structures, bare NPs can optionally be used in repetition**: *We searched endlessly for `a spring` or `a cave` to spend the night, but neither `spring` nor `cave` could be found.*

I don't think *spring* and *cave* are "repeated nouns" in [vi] or "matched nouns" in [vii]. [vi] only discusses "repeated nouns" connected with a preposition. [vii]'s *`mother` and `child`*, the only one without any preposition, is different from *neither `spring` nor `cave`* in that *spring* and *cave* cannot be said to be matched nouns like *mother* and *child* can.

Although it starts with "Similarly", therefore, the last sentence seems to be discussing a different category from [vi] or [vii]. If so, what exactly does CGEL mean "**in coordinate structures, bare NPs can optionally be used in repetition**"?

If that statement is to be literally accepted, the following variants of the example sentence should also work:

> (1) *We searched endlessly for `spring` or `cave` to spend the night...*
>
> (2) *We searched endlessly for `spring` and `cave` to spend the night...*
>
> (3) *...but `spring` or `cave` could not be found.*
>
> (4) *...and finally `spring` and `cave` could be found.*

But none of these works for me. (Please let me know if any of these works for you.)

Therefore, there must be some other **implied** criteria for allowing repeated bare NPs in coordinate structures.

What are the criteria?

The only criterion I can think of is that the repeated coordinate structure has to be preceded by the coordinating marker such as *neither*, *both* and *either* as in *neither `spring` nor `cave`*. Are there any other criteria?

Comment: I think you have used all possible usages of   noun phrases being repeated.  Neither spring nor care; spring or cave; spring and cave; both spring and cave, exemplify them. I think 'not only spring, but also cave, whether...or' etc speak for coordinating structure, do they? Is it that coordinating structures should have a coordinating conjunction...?

Comment: Was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzO8J.png) really what it looked like in CGEL to you? I find the very notion that they may have employed such garishly outlandish typography more than merely mildly upsetting.

Comment: *We three kings of orient are, / 
Bearing gifts we traverse afar /
**Field and fountain, moor and mountain,** / 
Following yonder star.*

Comment: @tchrist The "garishly outlandish typography" was used to represent underlines, which I don't know how to employ here. I didn't want to embolden texts instead of underlines, so I had to improvise. Never thought it would upset anybody; it took some effort.

Comment: @tchrist Do you think "field" and "fountain" are **matched nouns** as in [vii]? How about "moor" and "mountain"?

Comment: Yes, I do think them matched nouns, just as they are in *over hill and dale* and in *come rain or shine*. Consider the famous postman’s creed: *“Neither snow nor rain nor heat nor gloom of night stays these couriers from the swift completion of their appointed rounds.”*  ¶ As for the u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲d̲ ̲t̲e̲x̲t̲, alas no, that’s not *easily* accomplished here, if a̲t̲ ̲a̲l̲l̲; you have my deepest sympathies.

Comment: @RamPillai I think you're right that 'not only...but also...' is also a coordination. I think 'whether...or' is simply 'A or B' so it's not another form of coordination. I'd like to also consider 'not only...but also...' but the question is already long and complicated enough so...// BTW, I'v substantially revised the question.

Comment: @tchrist I also think they're matched nouns. But I'm sure you'll agree that _spring_ and _cave_ are not matched nouns. So they're not exactly helpful to my **revised** question. (Please see the edit.)

Comment: All they are saying is that if you use a coordinated pair once with articles, you can use the pair again without them. _We searched endlessly for **a spring or a cave** to spend the night, but neither **spring nor cave** could be found._ The coordinates themselves don't need to be repeated (_spring_ after _spring_) or matched (_start_ to _finish_) as they are in vi and vii respectively. This is a third type.

Comment: @TinfoilHat That used to be my reading, but I don't think it's the correct reading anymore.

Comment: @TinfoilHat If your reading of CGEL is right, this should be wrong without any determiner. _We searched endlessly for either spring or cave._ Is this wrong?

Comment: That sounds pretty wrong. But even if it were correct, how does it make *in coordinate structures, bare NPs can optionally be used in repetition* wrong? We do drop the articles in coordinates sometimes, (subject to somewhat mysterious qualifications). See [Zero in Enumerations and Pairs of Words"](https://bit.ly/2QqlWFH) and [Omission of the indefinite article to eliminate ambiguity](https://bit.ly/2ISSG6b). I only skimmed [this paper](https://bit.ly/2WmyTEj), but see p. 12, Noun classes in coordinate expressions and their combinations. I would put these in CGEL's "matched nouns" bucket.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Maybe your reading is correct, since the following sounds wrong: _We searched endlessly, but neither spring nor cave could be found._

Answer (score 1):

## Summary

No, the repeated coördinate structure does ɴᴏᴛ have to 
be preceded by a coördinating marker such as *neither*, *both*, or *either*
for bare NPs to be usable.

You just haven’t done so in your examples,
but yours are all failing for their own reasons.

---

## Details, Details, and More Details

Their original is the only one that works tolerably well as written.  The other
three you offer all have problems, but not because of using bare NPs. Here is theirs:

> 1. We searched endlessly for a spring or a cave to spend the night, 
>      but neither spring nor cave could be found.

That phrasing is still more awkward than need be. Have *you* ever spent the night 
in a spring? I certainly have not done so.

Possible solutions to this confusion include:

- We searched endlessly for a spring or **for** a cave to spend the night, but neither spring nor cave could be found. (1a)
- We searched endlessly for a spring or a cave to spend the night **in**, but neither spring nor cave could be found. (1b)
- We searched endlessly for a spring or a cave **in which** to spend the night, but neither spring nor cave could be found. (1c)

> 2. We searched endlessly for a spring or a cave to spend the night,
>      but spring or cave could not be found.

This provokes confusion because we cannot be sure how the negative applies
to the two disjoined subjects: does it apply to each one individually or to
both as a pair?

To resolve this problem while still using bare NPs, any of these would work:

- ...but no spring or cave could be found. (2a)
- ...but no spring nor cave could be found. (2b)
- ...but spring and cave were not to be found. (2c)
- ...but spring and cave alike were nowhere to be found. (2d)
- ...but spring and cave alike were not to be found. (2e)
- ...but spring and cave alike could not be found. (2f)
- ...but spring and cave alike could be nowhere found. (2g)
- ...but (we) could find neither spring nor cave. (2h)
- ...but (we) found neither spring nor cave. (2i)

Notice how those use bare NPs irrespective of the conjunction used,
and also how not one of them has to prefix the pair using *both*.

> 3. We searched endlessly for a spring or a cave to spend the night,
>      and finally spring and cave could be found.
> 4. We searched endlessly for a spring or a cave to spend the night,
>      and finally both spring and cave could be found.

These two share the same two fundamental problems that make them unworkable as written.

- Their first problem is one of semantics, not one of syntax. Endless searches never end in success.  A search without end cannot be said to have succeeded in the end.  Therefore successful searches must never be called endless ones. Another way of searching endlessly is searching in vain, or searching futilely, or searching fruitlessly. The last of those, which I rather like, leads to the parallel observation that because a fruitless search bears no fruit, any search that
  does ultimately bear fruit can never be said to have been a fruitless one in the end.
- But their second problem is that when *could be found* is used in a positive sense, it again provokes confusion.
  This is because syntactically the negation of the completed action *we could not find* **ɪꜱ ɴᴏᴛ** (or should not be)
  *we could find*. Rather, it is *we **did** find* using a sort of “definite past” construction to guarantee that the action has completed. You need to somehow signal the perfective aspect here, not the imperfective aspect. You might be able to get away with the periphrastic *we were able to find*, but this remains slightly ambiguous with no ✻*did be* solution available here because you can’t use *did* with *be* in Standard English.

To fix both problems, try combining one of these as the first clause:

- For many hours we searched fruitlessly for a spring or a cave in which to spend the night... (3a)
- For many fruitless hours we searched for a spring or for a cave in which to spend the night... (3b)
- For many fruitless hours we searched for a spring or a cave to spend the night in... (3c)

with one of these as the second clause:

- ...until right before sunset we came upon spring and cave together. (4a)
- ...until we suddenly came upon spring and cave alike just before sunset. (4b)
- ...until right before sunset we came upon spring and cave in the very same place. (4c)
- ...and then just before sunset we finally came upon spring and cave in the very same place. (4d)
- ...and just before sunset we came at last upon spring and cave nestled within a hidden glen. (4e)

Notice how all of those still use bare NPs.

That said, you might perhaps prefer to consider postpositive *alike* and postpositive
*together* to be “coördinating markers” in much the same way as you have already treated
*neither*, *both*, and *either* when those are preposed instead of postposed
the way *alike* and *together* are in my solutions. And *both* can also be postposed, making these two equivalent formulations:

- **Both Mom and Dad** had told me that it was ok.
- **Mom and Dad both** had told me that it was ok.

Comment: +1 for the details teasing out the real issue by pointing out the hidden problems of my own variants. I mostly agree that they are problematic. // Do you think _spring_ and _cave_ are subsumed under "matched nouns" as shown in [vii]? If so, what's the criteria for determining whether two nouns in coordination are "matched nouns"? If not, why do you think (2c) _...but spring and cave were not to be found_ works? I don't think any random two singular count nouns can be in the 'and' coordination without a determiner or a coordinating marker or an adjunct such as _alike_.

Comment: Also, I notice your answer is based on my earlier version of the question prior to the revision. Since 'endlessly' and 'for the night' are ambiguous, how about we just get rid of them. Now, let's evaluate (1) and (2), in the revised question, without the phrases: (1) _We searched for spring or cave, but..._ (2) _We searched for spring and cave, but..._ Do you think both are well formed?

Comment: Once I get your answer to all of my questions in comments, I will revise the question again to remove any unnecessary problems in the alternative example sentences.